# What do you think about "Magento Associates"?

Tags: company

Magento announced in this blog post: [Strengthening our Solution Partner Program](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/strengthening-our-solution-partner-program/) a new partner status (?): *Magento Associates*

> Our goal is to help Magento Associates develop the skills they need to
>   become Magento Enterprise experts and engage in Enterprise
>   implementations. These companies may or may not have the goal of
>   joining the Solution Partner program, but we will provide them the
>   resources and opportunity to do so if they choose.

1. What do you think this is? Some kind of Partners but with no certified developers?  Lower status for Solution Partners?
2. Does anyone has more info about fees for becoming a Magento Associate
3. Why would a company do that?
4. What benefits would a Magento Associate have?

Comment: Just a rebrand, for EE. From a company that can't even run useful support forums for their software. One day, the forums may return to being postable... Heh. Watching for skating cows and flying pigs on that one.

Answer (score 3):

Good post about the subject: http://www.gxjansen.com/improved-magento-partner-program-levels-now-actually-based-on-quality/

Make sure to read the comments, interesting comment from sonassi.

Answer (score 0):

Annual fee for Magento Associate program is $5000.